# document.referrer does not retrieves value for new tab : Safari

Tags: javascript, tabs, safari

Here are two sample pages

Page 1:

```
<html>
<title>Page 1</title>
<body>
This is page 1
<a href="page2.html">Click to go to page 2 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<title>Page 2</title>
<script>
function test() 
{
alert(document.referrer);      
}
</script>
<body onload="javascript:test();">
This is page 2
<a href="page1.html">Click to go to page 1 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

In safari, when link clicked from Page1, document.referrer does not seems to work/hold values.

It works fine in Mozilla.

Comment: Pass it in the query string, like `rel=page1.html`

Comment: i cannot update the URL.I need this, to track if page2 has been opened by clicking page1 or the url for page2 has been pasted in address bar(in that case the document.referrer should be null).This dosen't seems to be working in safari.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a bug in Safari, it seems to have existed in Chrome as well: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1935 (I've tried it myself and am also getting an empty referrer in a new tab)